# Press windows key with pyautogui or python

Tags: python, pyautogui

pyautogui has this functions such as pyautogui.press(key), but I can't figure out how to press the windows key, can someone help me in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string representation of the Windows key is `"win"`:

```py
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.press("win")
```

Alternatively, you could pass the `"winleft"` and `"winright"` strings, which press the left and right Windows keys, respectively.

The [`pyautogui` documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has a [list of keyboard strings](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys) which can be passed to the `press()`, `keyDown()`, and `keyUp()` functions.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

According to pyautogui [source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/_pyautogui_win.py)(take a look at line 123) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) keyboard map the windows button key name is 'super'.

`pyautogui.press('super')`